# t.apply is not a function

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, jsfiddle

In updating this chart from D3.V3 to D3.V4 I'm hitting this error:

```
TypeError: t.apply is not a function
```

https://jsfiddle.net/horacebury/bygscx8b/16/

I can't see where to change the code as I'm not actually using a D3 function 'apply'. The Angular code has not changed and was working fine with D3.V3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this (I think its a mix of d3.v3 and d3.v4):

```
  var xAxis = d3.select(".axis").call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(5));
  var xAxis = d3.select(".axis").call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5));
```

should have been this as below (since you using d3 v4)

```
  var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5);
  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(5)
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/a8dr9cL4/)

Comment: Because of the change documented here? https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#axes-d3-axis

Comment: i guess you got mixed up with the change set :)

Comment: Yes. I'm not completely read-up on everything in D3 yet but have to make use of it nevertheless.